# Why do I get a stray element with difflib.ndiff?

Tags: python, python-3.x, difflib

Minimal working example:

```
In [3]: a = ('r1', 'r2', 'r11', 'r6', 'r1', 'r2', 'r7', 'r8')                                                                                           

In [4]: b = ('r1', 'r2', 'r1', 'r6', 'r1', 'r2', 'r7', 'r8')                                                                                            

In [5]: list(difflib.ndiff(a, b))                                                                                                                       
Out[5]: 
['  r1',
 '  r2',
 '- r11',
 '?   -\n',
 '+ r1',
 '  r6',
 '  r1',
 '  r2',
 '  r7',
 '  r8']
```

Can someone please explain why there's a newline character as the fourth element in the output list? What can I do to not get that element as `ndiff` output, but only the rest of the list?

Comment: Why don’t you look at the source code? It’s there, on your computer. You can always filter them out by removing the items in the result that `startswith(‘?’)`

Comment: I figured out a way around it. That's not the problem. The problem is if I don't know why this is happening and go about using ndiff on huge files, I don't know what other kinds of unexpected diff I may get and ones that may silently go unnoticed!

Comment: If you read he documentation you will probably get all the details and some other useful information as well. Win-win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ndiff` expects the lines you pass in to end with newline characters, like this:

```
a = ('r1\n', 'r2\n', 'r11\n', 'r6\n', 'r1\n', 'r2\n', 'r7\n', 'r8\n')
b = ('r1\n', 'r2\n', 'r1\n', 'r6\n', 'r1\n', 'r2\n', 'r7\n', 'r8\n')
```

In the docs for [`difflib.Differ.compare`](https://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ.compare), which is what `.ndiff()` calls [under the hood](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/84ac4376587e35d16b4d0977c4f330d9d04b690a/Lib/difflib.py#L1368), we see this (emphasis mine):

> ```
> compare(a, b)
> ```
>
> Compare two sequences of lines, and generate the delta (a sequence of lines).
>
> Each sequence must contain individual single-line strings **ending with newlines**. Such sequences can be obtained from the `readlines()` method of file-like objects. The delta generated also consists of newline-terminated strings, ready to be printed as-is via the `writelines()` method of a file-like object.

The output you're getting makes sense, lines that start with `?` are for highlighting what changed. In this case it's drawing a `-` under the second `1` in `r11` to show you that it was deleted. `difflib` is expecting that you will use the output like this

```
print(''.join(difflib.ndiff(a, b)))
```

so it needs to end any lines it adds with a newline.

You can add the newlines to your original values with a list comprehension

```
a = [line + "\n" for line in a]
b = [line + "\n" for line in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to figure out the exact issue: Here's what happens:

[image]

So, the ndiff is trying to give you more info: you can convert r11 to r1 by deleting the last character 1. Note: _ is used to copy the output from the previous commmand.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#differ-objects):

> Lines beginning with ‘?’ attempt to guide the eye to intraline
>   differences, and were not present in either input sequence. These
>   lines can be confusing if the sequences contain tab characters.

It's basically an artificial difference. It *seems* to have something to do with the similarity between `r1` and `r11`; changing the element in `a` to `r7` gets rid of the `?` diff. I'm not sure what constitutes "similar", though.

Comment: I removed `r` from  the beginning of the strings, and I get rid of that `?` line. Doesn't make sense with your explanation. Thanks anyways. I wonder how can I get the diff right with `r` included.